# PDO fetchAll group key-value pairs into assoc array

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Every now and then, I get into a situation when I have a query similar in kind to:

```
SELECT `key`, `value` FROM `settings`;
```

In this case, I want to get an associative array, using values of `key` & `value` as respective entries of that array, e.g. if the database contained: `('first_name', 'Tom'), ('last_name', 'Jeferson')`, the array should be `array('first_name' => 'Tom', 'last_name' => 'Jeferson');`.

The most common way to do this is:

```
$settings_flat = $db
    ->query("SELECT `name`, `value` FROM `settings`;")
    ->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$settings   = array();

foreach ($settings_flat as $setting) {
    $settings[$setting['name']] = $setting['value'];
}
```

*The other way to do this is by calling `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN)` two times & then using `array_combine` to create the array. However, since it involves two calls two the database, I leave out this as an option.

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

For your problem there is pretty ready solution, that is:

```
$q = $db->query("SELECT `name`, `value` FROM `settings`;");
$r  = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
```

Works for me, on PostgreSQL 9.1, and PHP 5.3.8 running on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Great! Didn't know about this constant. Apparently PDO fetch documentation page doesn't list them all. Though, `AS name, AS value` bit is redundant.

Comment: Also, didn't know, my IDE highlighted it for me...)

Comment: Is there a way to use `PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR` and have the output as an `object` at the same time?

Comment: Here's where all constants are documented:
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php

Comment: I'd used this before, but couldn't remember how.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks !

Comment: @adamj, to return the value column(s) as objects, use: \PDO::FETCH_GROUP|\PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE|\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC

Comment: Also for anyone looking to return an entire row indexed by the first column so ("id" => "name", "value", "age") etc. You would use (PDO:: FETCH_UNIQUE).

Answer (score -5):

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT `name` AS name, `value` AS value FROM `settings`;");
$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```