# Multiple fetch() actions on a single instance

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need to display the same query multiple time but without array because i need different data

example

```
$re = $bdd->query("SELECT url, name FROM type);
while($do = $re->fetch()) {
    echo $do['url'];
}
while($do = $re->fetch()) {
    echo $do['name'];
}
```

What is the best solution ? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [PDO fetchAll group key-value pairs into assoc array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7451126)

Comment: Why do you insist on doing it without an array? Of course you should use an array! Just fetch both columns beforehand, then use your two distinct loops to output one or the other.

Comment: One array for each ? but why `$re->fetch()` work only for the first ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `->fetch` twice. Get a complete list with [`->fetchAll`](http://php.net/pdostatement.fetchAll).

```
$re = $bdd->query("SELECT url, name FROM type");
$result_list = $re->fetchAll();
// …
foreach ($result_list as $do) {
    echo $do['url'];
}
// …
foreach ($result_list as $do) {
    echo $do['name'];
}
```

This is much easier. It simply utilizes the *resulting array* twice. Which is why there's no point in issueing the database query twice.

Comment: (I'm very very sure we do have a duplicate on this. Just hard to uncover for such simple stuff.)